# How can we force one line proof environment to stick to its associated theorem environment?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, page-breaking, amsthm

In my LaTeX document, some of the proofs are one-liners:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{property}[theorem]{Property}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-5]

\begin{property}
\lipsum[1]
\end{property}
\begin{proof}
By construction.
\end{proof}

\lipsum[6-8]

\end{document}
```

Sometimes, the proof is printed at the top of a page, which really looks ridiculous. What is the best way to stick this kind of one-line proof to its associated theorem environment ?

Comment: Can you provide a working document, not just fragments out of context?

Comment: I have just reworked the sample.

Comment: this is ordinarily considered a good place to break a page, so the only way i can think of to "force" it not to break is to use `\needspace`.  (would be glad to learn of something better.)

Comment: The rereworked sample, where the package lipsum is used instead of the package blindtext, reproduce the issue on my Debian Jessie box.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I put your suggestion as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle: Well, actually you could have asked *barbarabeeton* first to provide before you just take over the suggestion and make a self-answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Actually you could have read her profile first and understand why she will not make any answer.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle: Oh, she answers questions, but apparently not ams-related ones ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the solution suggested by Barbara:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{property}[theorem]{Property}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-5]

\needspace{13\baselineskip}
\begin{property}
\lipsum[1]
\end{property}
\begin{proof}
By construction.
\end{proof}

\lipsum[6-8]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're facing a trade-off between two less-than-ideal outcomes: Either move the entire theorem-like environment (which can contain quite a few lines, right?) to the following page in order to avoid a page break between the theorem-like environment and the associated one-life proof environment, *or* enlarge the current page by 1 or 2 lines. You've already provided a solution for the former option; its downside is that you might have a sizable "hole" at the bottom of a page. To implement the second option, you could write something like

```
...
\begin{property}
\lipsum[1]
\end{property}
\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip} % or, possibly, "2\baselineskip"
\begin{proof}
By construction.
\end{proof}
...
```

At any rate, I wouldn't apply this modification until the very end of the writing of the article.